# ExtJS Accordion layout hide child elements

Tags: javascript, extjs, accordion

How to override the logic for calculating the next expand/collapse child panel  using **Accordion layou**t?
I am interested in it due to the inability to hide from the user chat sequencer child panels without violating expand/collapse of visible panels.

```
MenuBoxPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 300, 
    layout: {
        type:'accordion',
        multi: false
    },
    region: 'west', 
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Panel 1'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Panel 2'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Panel 3'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Panel 4'
    }]
});
var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    minHeight: 420,
    items: [MenuBoxPanel],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
MenuBoxPanel.items.items[1].hide();
```

[View link](http://se.uploads.ru/t/SQf1V.png)

Comment: It's not really clear what you try to achieve...Can you describe the scenario in steps? :) You have an accordion where first item is expanded. You hide the second item... What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I need the ability to hide from the user accordion elements without removing them from the panel, while switching to the child elements should ignore hidden elements. The screenshot shows that this is not happening and after switching elements - hidden elements are not ignored. 
I am sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's a bug. The item's `collapsed` property is set to 'top' and the `isCollapsingOrExpanding` is set to 1. If you set the `collapsed` property to true and the `isCollapsingOrExpanding = undefined` it works again :) So after you hide you can try setting those to these values and it works again..

http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/5KBfJ/1/

```
var menuBoxPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 300, 
    layout: {
        type:'accordion',
        multi: false
    },
    region: 'west', 
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Panel 1'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Panel 2'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Panel 3'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Panel 4'
    }]
});
var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    minHeight: 420,
    items: [menuBoxPanel],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
setTimeout(function(){
    var item = menuBoxPanel.items.getAt(1).hide();
    item.collapsed = true;
    item.isCollapsingOrExpanding = undefined;
}, 2000);
```

Comment: but after showing hidden items bug reappears. strange, but after the show these (hidden) elements called COLLAPSE event for expanded  items.